# Java inputstream giving io.filenotfound exception while working on other URL

Tags: java, android, json, inputstream

I'm writing an Android app. Now I try to get JSON from an URL with this method:

```
public String getInfo(String adress) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(adress);
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    int status = uc.getResponseCode();
    InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader inRead = new InputStreamReader(in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inRead);
    String line;
    String result = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
    }
    return result;
}
```

On this url: http://www.rtvlansingerland.nl/tag/nieuws/?json=get_posts this method is perfectly working while on this url: http://www.rtvlansingerland.nl/?json=get_post&id=24411 the status variable goes to 400 which gives a url not found exception and `uc.getInputStream()` returns a filenotfound error.

If I open the URL in my browser it returns perfectly valid JSON (checked with jsonlint).

Does anyone have an option what could be wrong?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Please add LogCat

Comment: @AwaisSoomro I think the op already solved the problem, because this question is from 2013.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך lol I didn't check for date, I'm using mobile app 

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use network connection on main thread and after that you should check whether the file exist or not on `URL` if exist then proceed

Comment: The method I gave is already running on a second thread, the check might be good but in this case I know the url exists.

Comment: Not url, you have to check `JSON` file on url